# How do I use hosted YUI with SSL?

Tags: javascript, yui

I have downloaded YUI onto my local server and linked through to the yui-min.js. The code i use is:

```
<script src="//mysite.com/scripts/yui3-3.17.2/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
```

This works fine in a HTTP environment but doesn't work when I switch to HTTPS.

My only bit of yui code is as follows:

```
    <script>
YUI({
    classNamePrefix: 'pure'
}).use('gallery-sm-menu', function (Y) {

    var horizontalMenu = new Y.Menu({
        container         : '#demo-horizontal-menu',
        sourceNode        : '#std-menu-items',
        orientation       : 'horizontal',
        hideOnOutsideClick: false,
        hideOnClick       : false
    });

    horizontalMenu.render();
    horizontalMenu.show();

});
</script>
```

I believe i need to use a combo handler to get this to work but i cannot understand the documentation on how this works. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: No error appears. It just doesn't seem to run the script under HTTPS environment.

Comment: Check your network tab...

Answer (score 2):

That is the complete code that works in https:

```js
<script>
YUI({
    classNamePrefix: 'pure',
    modules: {
     'gallery-sm-menu': {
      fullpath: 'js/yui-gallery-master/build/gallery-sm-menu/gallery-sm-menu.js'
     },
     'gallery-sm-menu-base-min': {
      fullpath: 'js/yui-gallery-master/build/gallery-sm-menu-base/gallery-sm-menu-base-min.js'
     },
  'gallery-sm-menu-templates-min': {
   fullpath: 'js/yui-gallery-master/build/gallery-sm-menu-templates/gallery-sm-menu-templates-min.js'
  },
  'gallery-sm-menu-item-min': {
   fullpath: 'js/yui-gallery-master/build/gallery-sm-menu-item/gallery-sm-menu-item-min.js'
  }
    }
}).use( 'gallery-sm-menu',
  'gallery-sm-menu-base-min',
  'gallery-sm-menu-templates-min',
  'gallery-sm-menu-item-min', function (Y) {

    var horizontalMenu = new Y.Menu({
        container         : '#demo-horizontal-menu',
        sourceNode        : '#std-menu-items',
        orientation       : 'horizontal',
        hideOnOutsideClick: false,
        hideOnClick       : false
        });
    horizontalMenu.render();
    horizontalMenu.show();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

YUI CDN (yui.yahooapis.com) doesn't support HTTPS endpoint. Gallery modules such as [`gallery-sm-menu`](https://github.com/smugmug/yui-gallery/tree/master/src/sm-menu) will loads from HTTP CDN as default. You need to define the module within YUI configuration object.

The example as follows. Please see also [YUI Global Object](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/yui/).

```
YUI({
    modules: {
        gallery-sm-menu: {
            fullpath: 'https://your-domain/your/path/to/module.js'
        }
    }
}).use("gallery-sm-menu", function (Y) {
    // do something.
});
```